# CSS Float Alignment

Tags: html, css, textbox

I want to display, for example, in the 1<sup>st</sup> line of text, a "your name" input box;    then use `float: left` for the text and the input box. In the 2<sup>nd</sup> line, I want to display same info (text add text box). How can you do the 2sup>nd line (text add text box) not join the 1<sup>st</sup> line (because I'm using `float: left`)?

I don't think `<br/>` is best solution for this problem. So what should I do?

Comment: Why isn't br the best solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert a div to clear your float between your lines

```
<div style="clear: left"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the info from being next to the floating elements, give them the `clear` CSS attribute, with the value either set to `both` or `left`.

The `clear` attribute tells the renderer that it should be rendered underneath any floating elements in the same parent element.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand how you want it laid out. You should look into the CSS `display` property.

See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/M68Qw/